# access element inside object

Tags: php, oop

```
var_dump($row_games_query)
```

gives the following-

```
object(MultiCore)#15 (1) {
  ["_data":"MultiCore":private]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    object(Core)#18 (1) {
      ["_data":"Core":private]=>
      array(2) {
        ["games"]=>
        string(5) "1,2,3"
        ["email"]=>
        string(8) "20012082"
      }
    }
    [1]=>
    object(Core)#17 (1) {
      ["_data":"Core":private]=>
      array(2) {
        ["games"]=>
        string(7) "7,8,9,0"
        ["email"]=>
        string(8) "20012083"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How do i access games?

I am trying the following but can't access the games.

```
  for ($i = 0; $i <= $row_games_query->length(); $i++) {
        $result = $row->get($i);
        $games_over_list = $result->games;
    }
```

Please Help.

Comment: You can only access it from within the `MultiCore` class. It's a private var.

Comment: instead doing `var_dump()` do 'echo "<pre>";print_r($obj);echo "</pre>";` You will get more clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a function to the Core class like

```
public function getGames() {
    return $this->_data; // the array of games
}
```

And calling it instead.